# Custom product collection filter not working during product search with magento 2 elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.2

I am using Magento 2 Commerce with elastic search enabled. I have a custom filtering of the product collection.

Now, when elastic search is enabled, custom filtering don't work however with MySQL search, it does work.

Any idea what's causing the issue or how elastic search is creating the product collection query?

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the used_for_sort_by to 1

For more details please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294187/27183